# Scrapy: How to save yield output into json using `python <spiderName.py>`?

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote code with several processes inside and I'm using it with `python spider.py`

Code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    title = response.css('.title::text').extract()
    info = response.css("div#info").extract()
    title = list(map(str.strip, title))
    info = list(map(str.strip, description))
    yield{
        'Title': title,
        'Main Info': info,
    }

2 same classes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    settings = dict()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'my agent'
    settings['DOWNLOAD_DELAY'] = 0.5
    settings['CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'] = 64
process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
process.crawl(ScrapySpider1)
process.crawl(ScrapySpider2)
process.crawl(ScrapySpider3)
process.start()
```

How can I save output into file.json with the same effect as `scrapy crawl -o file.json?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuring `FEED_URI` for `CrawlerProcess` should get you the same result as `scrapy crawl -o file.json`

```py
settings['FEED_URI'] = 'file.json'
```

Comment: Ow... I forgot about this parameter, thank you very much for reminding me =)